# Problema em instalar um script PHP

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, hospedagem

Estou com um problema para adicionar um script de chat online em minha hospedagem, no localhost funciona perfeitamente, mas pela hospedagem não Alguém poderia me ajuda?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pela hospedagem está dando esse error:

> The application couldn't connect to the given database. Please double
>   check all of the values in the Database settings section and make sure
>   your database is running.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda nessa questão o q pode ser?

Comment: No seu arquivo de conexão você está colocando as configurações do banco de dados do seu servidor?

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente você está colocando as informações de configuração de banco de dados do seu ambiente local. Verifique esses valores.